Yarn Berry - No Releases folder
Really simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to. When I run yarn set version stable, I get the confirmation that the version was set to 4.1.1. However, in my .yarn folder, there is no .yarn/releases folder created for shipping the package manager with the project. It's causing my Docker build to fail, because the configuration is trying to use Yarn v1
Configuration:

Platform: Windows 10
Node.js: v18.18.2
NVM: v1.1.11 (Used to install Node.js)
Scoop: v0.3.1 (Used to install NVM)

If you were to isolate the build steps to get here, it would be:

Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing get.scoop.sh | Invoke-Expression
scoop install nvm
nvm install 18.18.2
nvm use 18.18.2
npx corepack enable
mkdir ~/test-project
cd ~/test-project
npm init -y
yarn set version stable
yarn install
yarn ls .yarn < Note the lack of a releases folder

It's weird because my colleagues who authored another Yarn project on a Mac got the release in their project directory. I've also never had this problem before, though I admit I usually just use NPM. The current project is a fork of the other one I mentioned (I needed it for testing purposes, and they didn't let me mess with their stuff).
Any links to documentation would be greatly appreciated. Running Get-Command yarn just points me to the global script install for Yarn v1, but when I run yarn --version I get confirmation that the correct version is installed.

Had the same problem on win 11 and yarn 4.4.1, adding the extra flag --yarn-path e.g. yarn set version --yarn-path stable works for me.

Thank you for the answer. I totally forgot I had asked this question, and did discover this at some point. Full credit for the right answer though. Cheers mate!
